# How to play .caf audio file on android platform (Firemonkey)?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rad

I have developed a firemonkey application. Using it's TMediaPlayer component I am recording a .caf audio file on iOS platform. I am sending this file to the server. And on android I am downloading it from the server, but android is unable to play it. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Android can't play .CAF files.  Don't use that format, it's an Apple CoreAudio format.  You have heard of .MP3, .AAC, and .WAV and so on, right? Those are the formats Android will play. Convert on iOS from .CAF to .AAC or .MP3 and upload to the server.